# XmlSerializer returns nothing in my Windows 8 Store App

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, xml-serialization

I have successfully deserialized my xml file using XmlSerializer in .Net but trying to serialize that data back to an xml file is becoming frustrating. When I try to serialize my classes I only get the root tag of the xml with no child elements. How can I serialize all my objects to get the correct xml with data? I have seen somewhere where someone suggested to add the classes to be serialized in a collection and then serialize that collection but I can't wrap my head around that or is there a simpler way of doing it? Any help is appreciated! Here is my code:

```
    Public Shared Function SerializeXml() As Byte()

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Data))
    Dim nameSpaces As XmlSerializerNamespaces = New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
    Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim result As Byte()
    Dim target As New Data()

    nameSpaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty)

    serializer.Serialize(mStream, target, nameSpaces)

    result = mStream.ToArray()

    Return result
```

And here is a generic sample of the xml with attributes:

```
<?xml version"1.0">
<RootTag>
  <ChildTag Label="Label1" Value="Value1"/>
  <ChildTag Label="Label2" Value="Value2"/>
</RootTag>
```

Edit: Here is my Data class:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot("DATA", [Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
Public Class Data
    Inherits Model


<XmlElement("CONFIGURATION")>
Public Property Configuration() As DataConfiguration
    Get
        Return Me._Configuration
    End Get
    Set(value As DataConfiguration)
        Me._Configuration = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Configuration As DataConfiguration


<XmlElement("FIELD")>
Public Property Field() As Field
    Get
        Return Me._Field
    End Get
    Set(value As Field)
        Me._Field = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Field As Field


<XmlElement("LIST")>
Public Property ListRoot() As List(Of ListRoot)
    Get
        Return Me._ListRoot
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of ListRoot))
        Me._ListRoot = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _ListRoot As List(Of ListRoot)

End Class
```

Comment: Could you show your `Data` class that is being serialized?

Comment: Show Data class definition

Comment: I have added the Data class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your issue here, `<XmlRoot("DATA", [Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>`. The [IsNullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx) property, when set to false, will omit the XML for items if they are equal to nothing. If you set the `IsNullable` to True, then it will emit a tag like this `<ListRoot xsi:nil = "true" />`. In your code example, since you just created a new `Data` class like this `Dim target As New Data()`, all of the members are `Nothing` by default. Since you've set the `IsNullable = False`, you should only see that root tag, and that would be a valid serialization of the data.

Comment: So how can I serialize the data back to xml without creating a new Data class?

Comment: @em007, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You should serialize the Data class that has the data you want to save. In your example, you create a new blank data class and serialize it, that's why the output is mostly empty.

Comment: I see what you mean about getting empty data because I'm creating a blank Data class. But how can I serialize the Data class without creating a new data class?

Comment: You don't have to create a new data class. Say you just deserialized one like this `Dim myData = serializer.Deserialize(InStream)`, then you serialized the same object like this `serializer.Serialize(OutStream, myData)`. In theory, you should have written out the same XML file that you read in.

Comment: Thanks Kratz! I see what you mean now, cleared things up for me!